# iOS globally catch NSurlExceptions that throw as WebException, converting to HttpException

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, system.net.webexception, httpexception

I am currently using moderhttpclient inside a xamarin.forms application.

The shared code which is used by my UWP application catches httpExceptions and reacts to these, I have been request to not add the capture of WebExceptions to this, so reaching out to see if anyone knows how to do the follow.

The api uses the modernHttpClient, and the excpetion we get back is a NSURLException which is given as a WebExcpetion. Is there a way in iOS / Xamarin.Forms to globally capture these webExceptions and then throw them as HttpExceptions for the shared code?

Please feel free to comment and request any additional information, the intent was to get links to docs explaining iOS NSURLExcpetions and manipulation. Though I am willing to share more, if easier.

Comment: Can you share detail about share code?

Comment: The shared code is irrelevant to my question, the only inclusion the shared code has is that it catches HTTPExceptions not WebExceptions.

this question is regarding converting NSURLExceptions or WebExceptions in Xamarin.Forms.IOS to HTTPExceptions